# Relationship of Two Coordinate Systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have two applications which use two slightly different coordinate systems, they are as follows:

Coordinate System 1 & 2 Range:

- Range of X = 0 to 850
- Range of Y = 0 to 1100

Now when I place the same image on these two systems they occur in different spots as the "starting" point of image differs. System 1 places the image based on the coordinates of the top left corner the image and System 2 places the image based on the coordinates of the bottom right corner of the image.

Here is an example the systems placing the image in the same spot:

System 1 Top Left of Coordinate System:

- x=0
- y=0

System 2 Top Left of Coordinate System:

- x=0
- y=47

System 1 Top Right of Coordinate System:

- x=699
- y=0

System 2 Bottom Right of Coordinate System:

- x=699
- y=47

System 1 Bottom Right of Coordinate System:

- x=699
- y=1053

System 2 Top Right of Coordinate System:

- x=699
- y=1100

My question is, how can I create a ratio that takes this into account and applies the same position based on these coordinate systems?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly:

- Adding an image to System 1 at position `(x, y)`, positions it `x` units from the left of the system origin and `y` units from the top of the system origin.
- Adding an image to System 2 at position `(x, y)`, positions it `x` units from the right of the system origin and `y` units from the bottom of the system origin.

To convert from positioning relative to the bottom right, to positioning relative to the top left, you need to change `x` in System 1 to `850 - imageWidth` in System 2, and change `y` in System 2 to `1100 - imageHeight` in System 2. Then you need to shift things since the two systems are quite aligned.

Based on the example you gave for two aligned images, it looks like:

- If an image with width `w` and height `h` is positioned at `(x, y)` in System 1, then it should be positioned at `(699 - w - x, 1100 - h - y)` in System 2.
- If an image with width `w` and height `h` is positioned at `(x, y)` in System 2, then it should be positioned at `(w - 699 - x, h - 1100 - y)` in System 1.

I hope that answers your question.